# Google Script Multiple Files to Multiple Google Drive Folders

Tags: javascript, forms, file-upload, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have a Google Script code which allows users to input two files in an HTML form and puts them into designated folders in my Google Drive. The code specifies to look for the folders by name and if they're not there to create them. It works perfectly when the folders don't exist in my Drive, but when the folders do exist it gives me this error:

> Exception: Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end.

When the folders do exist in the Drive I'd just like for the files to be deposited there.

I am not very experienced in Java, but I suspect the issue is with the folders.hasNext() statements around lines 17-21 and 23-27, or the way I am defining the two folders.

```
function doGet(e) {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html');

}

function uploadFiles(form) {

 try {

var dropbox = "barGraph";
var dropbox2 = "myPlate";
var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);
var folder2, folders2 = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox2);

if (folders.hasNext()) {
  folder = folders.next();
} else {
  folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
}

if(folders2.hasNext()){
  folder2 = folders.next();
} else {
  folder2 = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox2);
}

var blob1 = form.bargraph;    
var f1 = folder.createFile(blob1);    
f1.setDescription("Uploaded by " + form.myName);
f1.setName(form.myName);

var blob2 = form.foodchart;    
var f2 = folder2.createFile(blob2);    
f2.setDescription("Uploaded by " + form.myName);
f2.setName(form.myName);

return "File uploaded successfully :" + f1.getUrl() + '; '+f2.getUrl();

  } catch (error) {

return error.toString();
 }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google-Apps-Script exception: Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40607752/google-apps-script-exception-cannot-retrieve-the-next-object-iterator-has-reac)

Comment: Shouldn't this `folder2 = folders.next();` be this `folder2 = folders2.next();`