# Trying to post index of google drive into sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am a begginer for javascript and am trying to export name and urls of my google drive folder to a sheet.

I have copied this code from internet.

```
function listFilesInFolder(Aman) {

  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(Aman).next();
  var contents = folder.getFiles();

  var file, data, sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.clear();

  sheet.appendRow(["Name", "Date", "Size", "URL", "Download", "Description", "Type"]);

  for (var i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {

    file = contents[i];

    if (file.getFileType() == "SPREADSHEET") {
      continue;
    }

    data = [ 
      file.getName(),
      file.getDateCreated(),
      file.getSize(),
      file.getUrl(),
      "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=no_antivirus&id=" + file.getId(),
      file.getDescription(),
      file.getFileType().toString()
    ];

    sheet.appendRow(data);

  }

};
```

hitesh is the name for my folder.

Unfortunately,

I am getting an error

that is

Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end. (line 3, file "Code")

also please guide me if I can make any alterations for this code to also crawl through folder in the folder "hitesh" and post index of the same.

Forever Grateful

Regards

manak

Answer (score 0):

Note that calling `next()` will get the next item in the collection of files or folders. So, you may want to check first if calling `next()` will return an item. Try enclosing your code with this condition,

```
while (files.hasNext()) { 

}
```

Also, if your folder's name is `hitesh`, then your should be using that in,

```
var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(Aman).next();
```

For additional insights, see this [GitHub post](https://github.com/jamietr1/google-docs-writing-tracker/issues/31) and this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40615349).