# Sending multiple attachments using Google Spreadsheet and Google Script

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, gmail

Im trying to send multiple attachments using Google Spreadsheet but I get the following error "Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end."

It does work, because it sends the e-mail to the first email-address in the list, but it fails for the second one.

I have seen similar questions here about it, but no solutions resolve my issue.

Here is the script:

```
function sendEmails() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var startRow = 1;
var numRows = 2; 
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2);
var file1 = DriveApp.getFilesByName('Maandbrief December.pdf');
var file2 = DriveApp.getFilesByName('Weekendbrief 7-9 december.pdf');
var data = dataRange.getValues();
for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];
    var message = row[1];
    var subject = "Maandbrief December en weekendbrief 7-9 december"; 
    MailApp.sendEmail({to:emailAddress, subject:subject, body:message, attachments: [file1.next(), file2.next()]})
}}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google-Apps-Script exception: Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40607752/google-apps-script-exception-cannot-retrieve-the-next-object-iterator-has-reac)

Comment: I don't understand this Google script enough to tell whether its a duplicate or not. Maybe the difference is that I'm not working in one specific folder and my file1 and file2 are already assigned really.

Comment: Actually the error occurred because file1 and file2 are assigned but not the way that you think. `getFilesByName` as well as other methods like `getFiles`, return an iterator object, that could not have a "next" file. Before using `next()` we should use `hasNext()` to avoid the error cited on the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 1;
  var numRows = 2; 
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2);
  var files1 = DriveApp.getFilesByName('Maandbrief December.pdf');
  while(files1.hasNext()){var file1=files1.next();}
  var files2 = DriveApp.getFilesByName('Weekendbrief 7-9 december.pdf');
  while(files2.hasNext()){var file2=files2.next();}
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];
    var message = row[1];
    var subject = "Maandbrief December en weekendbrief 7-9 december"; 
    MailApp.sendEmail({to:emailAddress, subject:subject, body:message, attachments: [file1, file2]})
  }
}
```

or this:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 1;
  var numRows = 2; 
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2);
  var n1=0;
  var n2=0;
  var files1 = DriveApp.getFilesByName('Maandbrief December.pdf');
  while(files1.hasNext()){var file1=files1.next();n1++;}
  var files2 = DriveApp.getFilesByName('Weekendbrief 7-9 december.pdf');
  while(files2.hasNext()){var file2=files2.next();n2++}
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  if(n1==1 && n2==1){
    for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
      var row = data[i];
      var emailAddress = row[0];
      var message = row[1];
      var subject = "Maandbrief December en weekendbrief 7-9 december"; 
      MailApp.sendEmail({to:emailAddress, subject:subject, body:message, attachments: [file1, file2]});
    }
  }else{
    throw('More than one file with given name.');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried the first one and it worked for me. Thanks a lot for this.