# Attachments on Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-apps

I'm having some problem when I put more then one attachments in Google Apps Script to send in a E-mail.

The part of the code that does this is

```
      reportPDF = doc.getAs('application/pdf')
      reportPDF.setName('Attachment1 - '+ rows[0][0] + ".pdf");
      
      var file1 = destinationFolder.createFile(reportPDF);  
      var file2 = DriveApp.getFilesByName("test.pdf");

      DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId()).setTrashed(true);
      
      emails.forEach(function(email) {
      MailApp.sendEmail(email, "Attachments  - " + rows[0][0], "Hello!", {
                        name: 'Good Practices',
                        attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF), file2]

    });
```

But when I run this, I Have this issue:

> Exception: Invalid argument: attachments (line 151, file
> "Email")

I have a .doc file1 that is filled in and then converted to PDF and another file2 that is already a PDF.

When I run with just the file1, i can send the email, but when i try with file1 and file2, i have this error. Can anyone knows what might be happening?

I run a lot of another suggestions that i read here in stack, but no one of then worked.

Comment: You are not supposed to edit your question to include an answers code and then report the new issue. Because the first issue you had is no longer visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

The issue is that `file2` **is not** of a type [FILE](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file) but an object of the [FileIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator) class.

On the other hand, `file1` **is** of a type [FILE](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file) and this is why it is working properly.

It is also a good practice to check if the file name exists before you sent the email.

### Solution:

```
function myFunction() {
  
  reportPDF = doc.getAs('application/pdf')
  reportPDF.setName('Attachment1 - '+ rows[0][0] + ".pdf");

  var file1 = destinationFolder.createFile(reportPDF);  // this is a file
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId); // put here the id of the folder
  var file2 = folder.getFilesByName("test.pdf"); // this is a file iterator

  DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId()).setTrashed(true);
  
  if (file2.hasNext() ) {
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, "Attachments  - " + rows[0][0], "Hello!",{
      name: 'Good Practices',                  
      attachments: 
          [
           file1.getAs(MimeType.PDF),
           file2.next().getAs(MimeType.PDF)
          ]    
  })};  
}
```

**References:**

- [getFilesByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilesbynamename)
- [createFile](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createfileblob)

Comment: Hi Marios! I made these changes to the code and got the following issue: 
- Exception: Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end. (line 157, file "Email").
I'll edit the code in the question so you can see how it looks!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. As you can see in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40615349/11225291) answer, there might be other files with that name. I would advice you to specify the folder name and not search in the full google drive. Do you have the `test.pdf` in a particular folder ?

Comment: Oh, thank you Marios! I have this two PDFs in a particular folder! I tried to change the name and have the same problem. So, may i change de DriveApp in File2 for DestinationFolder, like in file1, when i search for then?

Comment: @Rafael I modified my answer. Put here `folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId)` the id of your folder (you can find it in the folder url) and then the script will look for a file with the exact name `test.pdf` in this particular folder. Make sure that the name matches exactly (no extra spaces or caps locs etc).

Comment: Otherwise instead of `folder` you can use `destinationFolder` if the `test.pdf` file is in the `destinationFolder` itself.

Comment: I'm still having the same problem Marios, even with the folder, sorry for not working. The code return the same exception that the irerator has reached the end. The error is in the line: 158 - file2.next().getAs(MimeType.PDF). Do you have any other idea of what might be happening? I tried a lot of things already.

Comment: @Rafael can you please make sure you have only **one** file with the exact name `test.pdf` in the particular folder you are looking for? Also try `test` without the `pdf` extension.

Comment: @Marcos i posted like a answer the exactly files that i have in my paste! There's just one test.pdf as you can see. After you see, i'll delete my answer with the image.

Comment: yes, but is it in the folder? sorry can't reproduce the issue @Rafael

Comment: yes, they're all in the same folder. i'll try to look one another way to solve this problem, don't know why it's happening haha

Comment: Done @Marios! Sorry for editing my question. I'll make another with this issue right now! Thank you so much!